# Pros vs Cons - HibernateUtil vs @Autowired SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, autowired, sessionfactory

I'm trying to better understand pros and cons of how we might use Hibernate. I'm experienced with having a HibernateUtil.java in which I call to establish/get the session for data access interactions. However, I've maintained applications that utilize @Autowired properties to implement a SessionFactory inside the DAO. If not obvious, we are using Spring MVC.

Here are some brief examples of how each of these might be used:

**METHOD A**

```
public class MyDao {

   public static void save() {
      Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); 
      session.beginTransaction();
      // ...
   }

}
```

**METHOD B**

```
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

   private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

   //... getter/setter for session factory

   public void save() {
      Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(); 
      session.beginTransaction();
      // ...
   }


}
```

I am curious as to why one method would be used over the other. Is there a performance or memory consumption difference between the two? Have you come across instances where injecting the bean gets in the way of accomplishing tasks efficiently? Should a service class instantiate an instance of a DAO in order to access it's methods or do you prefer to use static methods?

What other pros and/or cons come with each option vs the other?

**REASON FOR CLOSING THIS QUESTION**

After reading more about this, I realize that it is an opinion-based question and I will not get a quantitative answer. This boils down to Singleton vs Dependency Injection. That's been discussed widely and I've read the main arguments about when to use and not to use each. I think there's discussion to be had about whether Hibernate should be configured as Singleton or DI, but Stack Overflow is not the place for that discussion. Regards.

Comment: Research on why singletons are bad and dependency injection is good.

Answer (score 2):

A big part of the justification made by the creators of Spring is that frequently you want to be able to swap out configurations for easy testing. Separating code and configuration and letting the framework put them together for you makes testing a lot easier because you don't need to write special case code to switch between a test-mode and prod-mode.

If you use the static way, your HibernateSessionFactory and the Configuration used to create it are hardcoded and either you don't have the option of testing against another implementation, or you have to write your own code to do it.

If you use spring-boot, you can have different profiles configure Hibernate differently. A trivial example would be to have Hibernate use H2 for running locally and unit testing, and some non-in-memory database elsewhere. Spring lets you specify this stuff declaratively with Java configuration and annotations. You specify which configurations work for which profiles, and you can pass in a profile as a system property when you run the code, or annotate your tests to indicate what profile they use.

Pre-Spring-boot you can do something similar, where tests use a test-specific Java configuration or context.xml.

With Spring-Data JPA most of your DAOs become interfaces where you can leverage preexisting CrudRepository methods, or that might have some custom queries in annotations. Spring handles a lot of implementation details for you, it is much less work than writing your own DAOs.